# What is the derivative of following equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am looking for the derivative of $\frac{dY}{dX}$ where $Y$ and $X$ are both a vector of $N\times 1$. And $Y$ is
$$(I- A \operatorname{diag}(X))^{-1} K\ ,$$
where $K$ is a vector of $N\times 1$, and $I$ is the identity matrix of $N\times  N$. A is a $N\times  N$ matrix.

I get this:
$$\frac{dY}{dX}
=
(I- A \operatorname{diag}(X))^{-1}  
A
(I- A \operatorname{diag}(X))^{-1} K\ .$$

However, RHS dimension is $N \times  1$ and $\frac{dY}{dX}$ should be $N\times N$.

I appreciate it if you tell me where I got wrong.

Comment: It would be simpler to ask the question with some matrix $A$ instead of the many $Z^T$.

Comment: Assume $X$ is the vector with components $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$. What is the derivative of $Y$ w.r.t. only $x_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\bx{\boxtimes}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vvec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$The $\sf Khatri$-$\sf Rao$ product $(\bx)$ is defined as
the columnwise Kronecker product $(\otimes)$
$$\eqalign{
F &= \LR{G\bx H} \;\iff\; f_k = \LR{g_k\otimes h_k} \\
H &= \mc{h_1&h_2&\ldots&h_n} \;\in\bbR{m\times n} \\
G &= \mc{g_1&\,g_2&\ldots&\,g_n} \;\in\bbR{q\times n} \\
F &= \mc{f_1\,&f_2&\ldots&\,f_n} \;\in\bbR{(mq)\times n} \\
}$$
or in terms of all-ones vectors $\LR{\o_n\in\bbR n}$
and the Hadamard product $(\odot)$
$$\eqalign{
G\bx H &= (G\otimes\o_m)\odot(\o_q\otimes H)
  \;\in \bbR{(mq)\times n} \\
}$$
It is useful in vectorizing expressions involving a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
&\vvec{A\:\Diag{x}\;B} = \LR{B^T\bx A} x \\
}$$

---

For your problem, define the following variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Diag x &\qiq dX = \Diag{dx} \\
B &= \LR{I-AX}^{-1} &\qiq dB = BA\:dX\:B \\
}$$
then calculate the gradient of the function like so
$$\eqalign{
y &= Bk \\
dy &= dB\:k \\
  &= \LR{BA\:dX\:B} k \\
  &= BA\:dX\;y \\
  &= \vvec{BA\;dX\;y} \\
  &= \LR{y^T\!\bx BA} dx \\
\grad yx &= y^T\!\bx BA \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your response.
To simplify it, may I rewrite it as $\frac{d log y}{dx} = BA$?

Comment: @AliK No, such a calculation would run as follows
$$\eqalign{
Y &= {\rm Diag}(y) \\
w &= \log(y) \\
dw &= Y^{-1}dy \\
  &= Y^{-1}\left(y^T\!\boxtimes BA\right)dx \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} &= Y^{-1}\left(y^T\!\boxtimes BA\right) \\
}$$